# What is the preferred way to format a long one-liner in an answer?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

When I am at the shell prompt, sometimes I write (unreasonably) long one-liners. The same happens when I answer bash questions here. Obviously, untils and fors and ifs get their own lines, but what about when there are six pipes chained together?

Aesthetically speaking, should I break up pipes into multiple lines:

```
cat /dev/random | grep 'foo' | sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' | paste -d '\n' - - | awk '{lord knows what goes here}' > /dev/null 
# or
cat /dev/random |
    grep 'foo' |
    sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' |
    paste -d '\n' - - |
    awk '{lord knows what goes here}' > /dev/null
```

I like the first way, but can see the advantages of the second. Is there an official position on this?

Comment: Why do you like the first way? In general I hate any code posted where I have to scroll right.

Comment: @DonkeyKong honestly, I don't know, I just never break these up in scripts or at the cli. It really bugs me to have to scroll right also, but for some reason I think | and > feel or look weird with a newline. The right scroll is bad but somehow breaking the chain feels worse.

Comment: I suppose you could do what you did here and show the same command both ways, if you made it very clear that it's the same command, but I have a feeling most people would rather you just do it the 2nd way.

Comment: Long one liners... another reason to banish shell script questions!